# Choosing all rows with one subindex in Pandas MultiIndex Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have the following table in a Pandas Dataframe with a MultiIndex (row, attribute). I have similar dataframes, which hold the values for 'class' and for 'probability', but these dataframes are with a single index (row).

```
                    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  ...     69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78
row     attribute                                                                                   
0       class       -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   ...     -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        probability -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   ...     -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
1       class       -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   ...     -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        probability -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   ...     -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
2       class       -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   ...     -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
        probability -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   ...     -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
```

How can I now set the values of all rows with attribute='class' to those in another dataframe with the correct shape? And similarly for 'probability'. I have tried the following:

```
df.loc[df.attribute == "class"] = labels[sorted.values]
```

which results into

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'attribute'
```

I am very new with MultiIndex, so any hints are appreciated, many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need:

```
df.loc[df.index.get_level_values("attribute") == "class"] = labels[sorted.values]
```

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(789)
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([np.arange(3), ['class','probability']],
                                  names=('row','attribute'))

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(6, 10)), index=mux)
print (df)
                 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
row attribute                                
0   class        3  2  1  3  4  8  4  1  8  0
    probability  1  1  9  8  9  4  1  4  1  3
1   class        8  1  4  9  6  5  3  5  4  9
    probability  7  6  6  5  0  8  5  4  8  1
2   class        1  4  2  6  5  9  0  6  2  8
    probability  8  8  9  1  4  2  1  5  5  9

labels = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2, size=(2, 10)), index=['class','probability'])
print (labels)
             0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
class        0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1
probability  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
```

If you want repalce values by repeated rows use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
mask = df.index.get_level_values("attribute") == "class"
df.loc[mask] = np.repeat(labels.loc[['class']].values, mask.sum(), axis=0)
print (df)
                 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
row attribute                                
0   class        0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1
    probability  1  1  9  8  9  4  1  4  1  3
1   class        0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1
    probability  7  6  6  5  0  8  5  4  8  1
2   class        0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1
    probability  8  8  9  1  4  2  1  5  5  9
```

**Detail**:

```
print (np.repeat(labels.loc[['class']].values, mask.sum(), axis=0))
[[0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

Comment: The former works perfectly, thank you! The latter still gives me the old: KeyError: 'attribute'

Comment: @rize - Thank you, also some sample was created.